# How to accept a deleted answer

Tags: discussion, questions

I posted a question here: [Is it possible to stop try catch from returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046971/is-it-possible-to-stop-try-catch-from-returning-null)

There was an answer I was going to accept, it was the best answer in my opinion, but the person deleted it. How can I get in contact with the person I forgot the name already so that they can undelete. Maybe a high rep user can see it? Or undelete it as an admin?

Help me find this person the answer was good. User had around 19k reputation.

Comment: There are two deleted answers there; the one by a 19.9k reputation user has a downvote on it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I think that even if it has a downvote on it, the user would like to recover it if he knew that his answer would be accepted.

Comment: It was [Elliott Frisch](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch); you could see if the URL he lists on his profile gives you an option to contact them. You could also leave a comment on another post of his, or try to [contact him on chat.stackoverflow.com](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch).